# EditText with vertical line

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to create the following custom EditText. How to make the vertical bar like the one on the picture?

[image]

Comment: you can use background or left drawable for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Style edittext_custom_style.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#75d0e2" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**xml:**

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom_style"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create same bar drawable and assign drawableLeft to edittext
Code put image in respective drawables like drawable-xhdpi etc
Sample is here.
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                style="@style/inputFieldStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Comment: please post a code example to be more clear. It´s only usefull as an answer if You show the questioner how to do it...